# How do I interpret this robots.txt file?

Tags: web-scraping

I am looking at this [robots.txt](https://www.marketscreener.com/robots.txt).

How do I know which part of the website can be **scraped**? Can this [page](https://www.marketscreener.com/BANK-OF-AMERICA-11751/) be **scraped**?

Answer (score 0):

The page you ask "https://www.marketscreener.com/BANK-OF-AMERICA-11751/" is not disallowed in robots. The read of the robots file would be:

```
Disallow: /formation/patrimoine/
All files and folders inside /formation/patrimoine/
Disallow: /content_*
All files and folders starting "with content_"
Disallow: /mods_a/setcesi.php*
The file "/mods_a/setcesi.php" and all querystrings to the file
Disallow: /prov.php*
The file "/prov.php" and all querystrings to the file
Disallow: /images/maps/static_map.php*
The file "/images/maps/static_map.php" and all querystrings to the file
Disallow: /*/news-twitter/*
Any file or folder that contains the path "/news-twitter/"
Disallow: /images/actions/2019/FD/*
Any file or folder inside "/images/actions/2019/FD/"
```

Still you need to guarantee that you do not hit any of this content that could be inside an ajax call or a image src. Also you should make sure to comply with basic rules of robots namely the number of requests you make to the page and specific copyrights.